# How to add a second master node with openshift-ansible

Tags: ansible, openshift, openshift-origin

I've created an initial small cluster with one master doing master/infra/etcd and 2 nodes for testing.
Then I add a third node and now I would like to add a second master node for ha.
But validation does not pass with this error message regarding my initial master node:

```
openshift_facts received a different value for openshift.master.ha
```

I've read on [gitter openshift](https://gitter.im/openshift/openshift-ansible?at=58c189d021d548df2cb3c233) that adding a second master is not supported but I dot not want to completely crash my cluster because I've now 3 projects on it and lot of apps.

Also in [official docs](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.6/install_config/install/advanced_install.html#multiple-masters):

> Moving from a single master cluster to multiple masters after installation is not supported.

Here's my ansible hosts file.

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd
new_masters
new_nodes

# Set variables common for all OSEv3 hosts
[OSEv3:vars]
# SSH user, this user should allow ssh based auth without requiring a password
ansible_ssh_user=root
openshift_release=v3.6

# If ansible_ssh_user is not root, ansible_become must be set to true
#ansible_become=true
openshift_deployment_type=origin
debug_level=2

osm_cluster_network_cidr=172.29.0.0/16
openshift_portal_net=172.30.0.0/16
osm_host_subnet_length=9
os_sdn_network_plugin_name=redhat/openshift-ovs-multitenant

# Native high availbility cluster method with optional load balancer.
openshift_master_cluster_method=native
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=cluster-master-lb-dev.example.com
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=cluster-master-lb-dev.example.com

# uncomment the following to enable htpasswd authentication; defaults to DenyAllPasswordIdentityProvider
openshift_master_identity_providers=[{'name': 'htpasswd_auth', 'login': 'true', 'challenge': 'true', 'kind': 'HTPasswdPasswordIdentityProvider', 'filename': '/etc/origin/master/htpasswd'}]

#metrics:
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=true
openshift_metrics_hawkular_hostname=hawkular-metrics.cluster.dev.example.com
openshift_metrics_cassandra_storage_type=pv

# host group for masters
[masters]
cluster-master-dev.example.com

# host group for etcd
[etcd]
cluster-master-dev.example.com

# host group for nodes, includes region info
[nodes]
cluster-master-dev.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra','zone': 'default'}" openshift_schedulable=true
cluster-node[1:3]-dev.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'primary', 'zone': 'default'}"

#[new_masters]
cluster-master2-dev.example.com

#[new_nodes]
cluster-master2-dev.example.com openshift_node_labels="{'region': 'infra','zone': 'default'}" openshift_schedulable=true
```

Is there any other method "non official" to add a second master node for ha no a cluster ?

Thanks